The LLM wrapper doesn't return a answer from a local model
I've created a LLM bot using python using streamlit as frontend interface to generate a blog article.
I will recieve a some guidelines to send to a prompt template and enerate the article, for do it so, I will use a HuggingFace model but instantiated locally(in a folder called "models").
The template are correct, and my LLM call(using invoke) is following the documentation, but doesn't respond. A raw text returns normally.
Did I missed something? I need to put an "await" on these cases?
The complete code is below:
 import streamlit as st
 from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
 from langchain_community.llms import CTransformers
 def getModelResponse(blog_topic, no_words, blog_style):
    try:

      llm = CTransformers(model='models/llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q8_0.bin',
                  model_type='llama',
                  config={'max_new_tokens': 256,
                          'temperature': 0.01})

      template = """Write a blog for {blog_style} job profile for a topic {blog_topic} within {no_words} words."""

      prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["blog_style", "blog_topic", "no_words"],
                      template=template)

      response = llm.invoke(prompt.format(blog_style=blog_style,blog_topic=blog_topic,no_words=no_words))

      return response
   
    except Exception as error:
      print(error)
      return error

 st.set_page_config(page_title="IA Generated blog",
               page_icon='',
               layout='centered',
               initial_sidebar_state='collapsed')

 st.header("Generate blogs ")

 blog_topic = st.text_input("Inform a blog topic")

 col1, col2 = st.columns([5,5])

 with col1:
   no_words = st.text_input('Inform the number of words')

 with col2:
   blog_style = st.selectbox('Context', ('Researchers', 'Data Science', 'People'), index=0)

 submit = st.button("Generate")

 if submit:
   st.write(getModelResponse(blog_topic, no_words, blog_style))`

I tried to use await but a error returned
